# Need help to prove pigeonhole problem

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

If we pick n+1 different positive integers with every integer is less than 2n. Prove that we can always find three numbers among these n+1 numbers that one is equal to the sum of the other two numbers.

These n+1 numbers will be chosen from 1 to 2n-1 totally 2n-1 choices. I am trying to do it by using the pigeonhole principle but I don't know how to set pigeons and holes in this case. Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: You haven't actually said what you want to prove about these integers that you're choosing.

Comment: Maybe he is trying to solve http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501320/puzzles-or-short-exercises-illustrating-mathematical-problem-solving-to-freshmen/501327#501327. Maybe.

Comment: I've edited the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: let the largest number in the set be $k<2n$.

Apply pigeonhole principle to the pairs of numbers which add up to $k$.