# if there are 5 points on a sphere then 4 of them belong to a half-sphere.

Tags: geometry, pigeonhole-principle

If there are 5 points on the surface of a sphere, then there is a closed half sphere, containing at least 4 of them.

It's in a pigeonhole list of problems. But, I think I have to use rotations in more than 1 dimension.

Regards

Comment: An answer is given by Calvin Lin [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/501334/11619). This is a duplicate in a way, but the topic of that other question is vastly different (a call for trick questions), so I am a bit reluctant to call it a duplicate.

Comment: So if you ever see a headline like "80% of Olympic Sites In The Last 20 Years Have Been In The ___ Hemisphere," it means bupkis.

Comment: @Bob Stein What is the maning of "bupkis" ? I never met this term...

Comment: @JeanMarie "bupkis" means "nothing at all". According to yourdictionary it comes from Yiddish. I think it's especially funny when used in a [string of synonyms](https://www.dictionary.com/e/16-synonyms-for-nothing/).

Comment: This was problem A2 from the 2002 Putnam Exam. See the solution here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=agJAWnfpNjY&ab_channel=MathsOlympiadTrainer

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Pick two distinct points out of your 5 (if all 5 are identical then they clearly all lie in a single hemisphere).  These two points define at least one great circle (if they're antipodal, they define infinitely many); pick a great circle they define.  This circle then cuts the sphere into two hemispheres.  Now pigeonhole the other three points between these two hemispheres.

Comment: Wow, this is the most beautiful paragraph I've seen this week. Thanks.

Comment: But the answer is sort of demoralizing, made me feel bad for not thinking of that.

Comment: @user4140 Don't be too demoralized!  A lot of problems like this come down to whether you can recognize the specific 'trick' - the thing to pigeonhole on; it's easy to see in retrospect but often impossible to spot from the other side.

Comment: I was thinking does this still holds if the sphere degenerates into  circle, seemingly not.

Comment: @zinking: Take 5 points on $\mathbb S^1$ such that the angle of any two neighboring points is $2\pi/5$. Then in every closed hemisphere there lie at most 3 of the points.

Comment: @wspin exactly, but I didn't came up with the proof

Comment: Can your method be used to show that there is a (closed) hemisphere which contains **exactly** 4 points? I ask because there are 5*4/2=10 combinations of 2 points and we can just take a combination whose greater circle divides the sphere into 2 halves, one containing 2 points and the other containing 1 point.