# Easy math proofs or visual examples to make high school students enthusiastic about math

Tags: soft-question, education, big-list

I'm a teacher in mathematics at a high school. Math has fascinated me for almost my entire life, so I would like to bring that enthusiasm to my students with beautiful yet easy to understand proofs or demonstrations. It's meant for students who are in their last grade of high school and will be going to university next year.

So what are simple proofs or visual examples that made you love math? The more examples the better! Answers with pictures would be even better!

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Things that I did already teach my students the basics of are: complex numbers, probability theorem, prime numbers, vectors, functions of more variables, a little bit about group theory, set theory. These are all things that I tried to mix with the things they should actually know for their exams. It's meant to give them an idea of what math is really about, not just repeating formulas.

Comment: Assuming that this is done after them finishing calculus, looking over the Weirstrass function and proving that it's continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere was very interesting to me. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function

Comment: I like combinatorial ideas with pictures: Sum of first $n$ (positive) odd integers is $n^2$; the connection between binomial coefficients, Pascal's triangle, and path-counting; those sorts of things.

Comment: It's a really small thing, but it marked me when I was in higschool, because it showed that sometimes, having another formalism simplify everything : proving that $\lbrace a^2+b^2 \; | \; a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace$ is stable by mulitplication with complex numbers.

Comment: Euclids proof of infinitude of primes is nice.

Comment: "Proving" that a number is prime by trying to order it in equal size buckets. Ok maybe not a "proof" in the formal sense, but something to spur interest in prime numbers.

Comment: A set of readings from Dunham's _Journey Through Genius_ would expose them to a lot of the proofs suggested here, while also supplying some of the history associated with it. (See [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/books/journey/content.shtml) for the table of contents.)

Comment: most of the proofs with induction have always fascinated me - i didn't learn it in school, but it is actually not that hard and there are nice examples with sums

Comment: in my opinion the most important factor here is that the teacher, so you, is fascinated by what he is presenting, so it might be a good idea to also add which area of mathematics do you prefer

Comment: The vast majority of comments and answers to this question cover math concepts way beyond what I learned back in high school- which is fine- but suggests that "for students in their last year of high school" is an ambiguous criterion. Especially so given the divide between high school seniors which have taken calculus, versus those who have not.

Comment: Is it better on http://matheducators.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: You may wish to check out http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733754/visually-stunning-math-concepts-which-are-easy-to-explain?rq=1 for some beautiful but easy to understand demonstrations.

Comment: Thanks so far! I extended my post with the things my students know so far

Comment: This question is related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/501320/61691

Comment: I suggested some interesting books then one of the moderators deleted my answer. I don't know the reason of his action...

Comment: @2000: The handling moderator gave the reason for deletion in their reply to your flag.

Comment: In high school my algebra teacher showed us a proof of the Fundamental Lemma in the theory of automorphic forms through the introduction of new algebro-geometric methods which really made realize the beauty and potential of math.

Comment: See also [this question on Mathoverflow about 'Proofs without words'](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words/29459)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

My teacher on $\pi$ day during math club did the [Buffon's needle experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon's_needle) (except with little sticks) which we thought was extremely cool. And a plus is that the proof is relatively simple, requiring only basic knowledge of probability and calculus.

The probability that a stick will cross a line is $$P={{2l}\over{t\pi}}$$
where $t$ is the distance between the parallel lines and $l$ is the length of the stick, so if you want to approximate $\pi$ directly, let $t=2l$ then calculate ${{total sticks} \over {crossed}}\approx \pi$

Comment: Now this is unique and would be really really cool to see live.

Comment: You can convince yourself of this without calculus. There are lots of online references. See http://www.cs.umb.edu/~eb/piday/ for some links, including this one: http://www.cs.umb.edu/~eb/piday/whypi.pdf

Comment: @EthanBolker Awesome!

Answer (score 39):

Here is one example that I find aesthetically pleasing, and which I have
found effective in 8<sup>th</sup>-grade classrooms.

Suppose you desire to cut out a triangle from the middle of a piece of paper,
not by punching the scissors through and cutting
the perimeter, but rather by folding the paper
and then cutting
straight through the folded paper.

The natural solution is to mountain-crease (red below) the angle bisectors,
and valley-crease (green dashed) a "perpendicular" from the incenter $x$:

---

[image: TriangleAngleBisectors]

       

<sup>(Figure from *[How To Fold It: The Mathematics of Linkages, Origami, and Polyhedra](http://howtofoldit.org/)*.)</sup>

---

What I find so pleasing is that when you perform this physically, the
angle bisectors meet at a point $x$ (the incenter), and one grasps 
Proposition 4, Book IV of Euclid viscerally. Naively, it could well
be that the bisectors do not meet at a point. But careful creasing
shows experimentally that they do.

I have found this tactile demonstration more convincing to 
(U.S.) 8th-graders than a two-column Euclidean proof.

<sup>(This repeats content from [my answer](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/7860/511) to a related question.)</sup>

Comment: This post has earned you a sale, you sly dog.

Comment: :-) $\mbox{}{}$

Answer (score 32):

I'll expand on my comment, now that I have some time.

For high school students, I really like discrete-math type ideas, particularly combinatorics. First, the vast majority of students are *never* exposed to these ideas (save binomial coefficients, and these, if introduced, are just strange symbols used to expand $(a+b)^n$, in my experience). And second, they often require relatively little prior knowledge, and offer the chance to think visually.

$\bullet$ First, that the sum of the first $n$ odd, positive integers is $n^2$. I'm currently teaching a remedial algebra class in college, and used the following as a bonus question on the first exam:[image]
 "This image shows that $1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 = 5^2$. What do you think $1 + 3 + 5 + \ldots + 99$ will be? Don't worry about simplifying, I'd prefer you to leave the answer as $[something]^2$. You can test your conjecture to see if it makes sense for $1,\ 1 + 3,\ 1 + 3 + 5,$ and $1 + 3 + 5 + 7$, also conveniently shown in the picture."

I got a few right answers (one particularly impressive, as they used squares to count how many odd numbers there were from $1$ to $99$), and even more amazing, everyone *stayed after class* the following day to ask me how to solve it! You can rest assured this has *never* happened with the material in the curriculum.

$\bullet$ To expand on binomial coefficients, note that a subset of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, such as $\{1, 3, 4\}$, uniquely determines a sequence $$\underset{1}{L}\ R\ \underset{3}{L}\ \underset{4}{L}\ R$$ of left/right steps, and thus paths (of the sort found in [this pdf](http://www.bmlc.ca/PureMath30/Pure%20Math%2030%20-%20Combinatorics%20Lesson%203.pdf)) from the top of Pascal's Triangle, to a certain spot, are counted by the binomial coefficient $5 \choose 3$ in a very natural way. [image]

This is also a very pleasing route to arrive at the famous identity $${n - 1 \choose k - 1} + {n - 1 \choose k} = {n \choose k},$$ as any path ending at the depicted point must pass through one of the two adjacent points above it; we simply add the numbers of those paths to see that ${4 \choose 2} + {4 \choose 3} = {5 \choose 3}$, as a calculation-free example. And of course, by exchanging L's with R's, we must have ${n \choose k} = {n \choose {n-k}}$.

Comment: I think that such combinatorial and "puzzle like" topics are the most likely to resonate with high school students: they incoprorate a strong visual element, they honestly pose interesting mathematical problems and they are hands on so the student can play around with them on their own.  Unlike other answers, the student can go home and produce more identities with a little help from sites like this one.  This avoids the "magic from heaven" feel other answers give, where the student is simply meant to be awed by a majestic but largely mystical result.

Comment: I can do this in my head with very little math. The width and height of the figure are the number of terms. So five terms gives you $5^2$ as an answer. You can count the terms by halving the sum of the first and last. So $(1+99)/2=50$ is the base of the square.

Answer (score 21):

[Hilbert's hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel) and other counterintuitive countability discussion are always fun.

A less abstract topic, yet still counterintuitive, could be the [Monty Hall problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem).

Comment: Yes Monty Hall problem is a really good one, and you could even bring in decks to show your students. This would definitely work well!

Answer (score 19):

I really liked the proof that you can raise an irrational number to an irrational number and get a rational number.

Consider ${}\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$. If this is rational, we are done (I think some answer on here shows that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational). If it is not, $\left(\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{\sqrt{2}} = 2$, so we are definitely done.

Comment: How do you reach the conclusion that $\left(\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{\sqrt{2}} = 2$? ([This comes to mind](http://star.psy.ohio-state.edu/coglab/Pictures/miracle.gif))

Comment: @HelloGoodbye: $\left(\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}^2=?$

Comment: @Semiclassical: Ah, it was simpler than I though. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Depending on one's temperament, this kind of argument can either arouse awe or aversion. Another polarising example (in a different area) is defining for instance the span of a set of vectors as the intersection of all subspaces containing all those vectors.

Comment: @Barry My issue with this is that you can't even make sense of irrational exponents until after calculus I (or II).  And even then, it's usually too subtle for the students to grasp.

Answer (score 17):

$$\begin{align}x = 0.999\ldots \\ 10x = 9.999\ldots\end{align}$$  so $$ \begin{align} 10x - x = 9x = 9 \\ \implies x = 1 \end{align}$$

Also in a right triangle with hypotenuse length $c$, legs $a,b$ and some angle $\theta$ opposite of $a$, then $$\begin{align}a^2+b^2 = c^2 \\ \implies \frac{a^2}{c^2}+ \frac{b^2}{c^2} = 1 \\ \implies \left(\frac{a}{c}\right)^2+ \left(\frac{b}{c}\right)^2 = 1 \\ \implies \sin^2(\theta)+ \cos^2(\theta) = 1\end{align}$$ A little more advanced for high school, you could show that there are as many natural numbers as there are integers.

$$\{1,2,\space \space   3,4,\space \space \space  5,6, \ldots \} \\ \{0,1,-1,2,-2, 3\ldots \}$$ The top list clearly contains every natural, and the bottom clearly contains every integer. Neither list is exhaustible so you can pair one natural number with every integer. If the students buy that, then maybe you could show them that the rational numbers are equinumerous to the naturals...

Comment: I think most high schoolers (assuming American here) who aren't already appreciative of math won't appreciate the seemingly counter-intuitive results that arise in set theory.

Comment: @Soke That may certainly be true. Although the particular example I gave doesn't have to be introduced in the language of set theory. It can be seen as an interesting property of infinity :)

Comment: I was introduced to the last one by solving the following problem: 'Suppose a submarine moves in 1D along the real number line according to the following constraints:  Its initial position is an integer, and it moves with a fixed integer velocity. Suppose that you are tasked with sinking this submarine and to accomplish this you are allowed to fire a missile, once per minute, at any location. Devise a strategy by which you are guaranteed to sink the submarine.' Thinking through this problem definitely helped.

Comment: I even think that the same result with rational numbers is nice for high schoolers. It is at least understandable, and certainly surprising. In the same vein, the proof that there are as many reals as continuous real functions, while not entirely understandable, *should* induce a certain awe (possibly not, but it's worth a try). Then remark that these "equal infinities" are much the same as the equivalence of $3 \text{ apples } \leftrightarrow 3 \text{ airplanes }$.

Comment: This is the typical false proof. First you *must* show that $10\cdot0,\bar{9}=9,\bar{9}$, which is far from obvious.

Comment: @egreg How about this? 

$$0.\overline{9} = 9\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{10^n}  = 9\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{10}}-1\right)  = 9 \left(\frac{1}{9}\right)  = 1$$

Comment: @graydad Yes, that's correct, but of course it uses series.

Comment: @egreg Which should be okay right? Assuming the high school student has seen geometric series. I also know a nice proof by contradiction where you suppose the existence of an $x$ where $0.\overline{9}<x<1$

Answer (score 15):

There are many interesting proofs of the Pythagorean theorem at [Cut the Knot](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/).

This is my favourite (as you might guess from my gravitar)

[image]

Let the length of the hypotenuses be $c$, and the length of the legs be $a$ and $b$, with $b$ being the longer (if either is longer). The area of the outer square is $c^2$, but it is also equal to the sum of the areas of the four coloured triangles and the area of the white square, and so the area is

$\quad4\times \frac{1}{2}ab + (b-a)^2$

$=\; 2ab + (b^2-2ab+a^2)$

$=\; a^2 + b^2$

---

Another nice one (attribution information is at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pythagoras-2a.gif)

[image]

---

A proof that I like to show Jr. High kids when I teach them programming is this. (It fits in with the programming since one of the things they do is to draw polygons by programming a simulated robot to trace out the polygon.)

[image]

Since the robot turns all the way around, the sum of $A$, $B$, and $C$ is 360. But we also know that $A = (180-a)$, $B = (180-b)$ and $C= (180-c)$. Thus

$\quad 360 = (180-a) + (180-b) + (180-c)$

$\therefore \; 2\times 180 = 3\times 180 - (a+b+c)$

$\therefore\; a+b+c = 180$

You can generalize the argument to show that for any polygon, the sum of the interior angles is $(n-2)180$.

Comment: `by programming a simulated robot to trace out the polygon` are you by chance teaching them LOGO?

Comment: No.  I teach them Java. But my whole approach is based on Seymour Papart's ideas, including the use of turtle graphics. More can be found at http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/Courses/turtle-world/ .

Comment: Wow thanks for all the effort man! very helpful

Answer (score 14):

[image]

$1+2+3+\dots +{(n-1)}$= ${n}\choose{2}$

Answer (score 13):

I rather like the [*bean machine*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_machine) as a physical introduction to probability, normal distribution and the concept of randomness:

[image]

Now that I think of it, I rather like mechanical devices in general that demonstrate mathematical truths/ideas. Leibnitz's mechanical binary calculator is another that springs to mind.

Comment: You should then check then [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1i-dnAH9Y4)  training video that presents the mechanical trajectory computer of the Iowa battlelhip. The most interesting part is the mechanical integrator. Or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NAsM30MAHLg) video Michelson's Harmonic Analyzer. I think the most interesting part is how it computes the inverse Fourier transform.

Answer (score 12):

There are several simple proofs I learned that made me love and appreciate math.

- the proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational
- the proof that there exist irrational $a$ and $b$ such that $a^b$ is rational
- any simple inductive argument
- the proof that there are an infinite number of primes
- Cantor's diagonalization argument for showing the cardinality of the reals is greater than that of the integers (though this may be pushing it for people with no set theory)

Comment: Yeah I prefer the 1st and 4th. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 12):

I like the proof that the harmonic series diverge.

The french mathematician Nicole Oresme gave an accessible proof of this. The idea behind his proof, which is grouping terms by power of one halves, was used by Cauchy for his condensation test. There is a [nice visualisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test#/media/File:Visualized_estimate_for_the_Cauchy_condensation_test.png) on Wikipedia of the process involved in the proof. 
[image: Wikipedia illustration of Cauchy condensation test]

Oresme proof is explained in detail [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicSeries.html) and [there (in video)](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/integral-calculus/sequences_series_approx_calc/convergence-divergence-tests/v/harmonic-series-divergent).

The [following article by S. Kifowit and T. Stamps](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/archives/physics116A10/harmapa.pdf) mentions several accessible proofs of the result (it is always enriching to see that there are several ways of proving a result). If you have already introduced the integral then you might consider **Proof 9**.

As I have first encountered this result (with a proof) at university, we used Cauchy's convergence test (**Proof 4** in Kifowit and Stamps article), but I think the idea is similar (to a certain extent) to the one used by Oresme.

**Edit** : N.B. the above picture does not show the harmonic series. However I have made the following illustration to show the grouping process in the case of the harmonic series :

[image: Illustration of Oresme proof]

Answer (score 12):

One mathematical fun fact that has left a strong impression on me when I was in middle school was the fact that you could state rules about random phenomena.

I remember I wasn't familiar with limits, but a teacher had decided to show us funny things about random walks on Excel (yep Excel... :)).

He basically made random walks on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with step size $1$, and showed us that the average squared distance after $n$ steps when we took a lot of walks was close to $n$.

I liked the fact that it felt like nothing could be said about the walks just by looking at them, but as soon as we computed the right quantity, order emerged.

Visual things are always nice. Plotting walks on the plane with colors, and showing how it looks so chaotic compared to the numbers/figures/functions we knew at the time did the trick I think.

Answer (score 11):

If they have not learned it in high school, I would recommend showing them how to derive the quadratic formula.  Since the proof only involves basic algebra, the students should be able to solve it on their own.  Showing them that they already have enough math knowledge to prove a helpful mathematical formula may allow them to share in your enthusiasm.

If they have already learned that, I would recommend showing them iterative series as shown in dynamical systems and the Mandelbrot and Julia fractal sets.  I always found this intriguing since the images were created with only mathematics.  If you need images, there are quite a variety online.

Answer (score 11):

When I was at high school I loved geometrical arguments, especially those which were both simple and profound. Later on, I discovered Combinatorial Geometry, which combines both Euclidean Geometry and Combinatorics. I think that a good idea would be to demonstrate the proof that
**No matter how the plane is 3-colored, it contains a monochromatic
unit distance segment**.
This states that the chromatic number of the plane is greater than (or equal) to 4. In my opinion the most elegant proof is by using [the Mosers Spidle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoserSpindle.html). The proof goes like this:

Toss on the given 3-colored plane the Mosers Spindle. Every edge in the spindle has the length 1. Assume that the seven vertices of the spindle do not contain a monochromatic unit distance segment. Call the colors used to color the plane red, blue and green. Name the seven vertices A,B,C,D,E,F and G.
[image]
Let the point A be red, then B and C must be one blue and one green. Therefore D is red. Similarly E and F must be one blue and one green. Therefore, G is red. We found a monochromatic segment DG of length 1 in contradiction to our
assumption.

There are several proofs of this result but in my opinion this will definitely bring enthusiasm to your students. I also love Ramsey like examples such as
**Six people are waiting in the lobby of a hotel. Prove that there are either three of them who know each other, or three of them who do not know each other.**
The statement is definitely far from being obvious. But, this is a beautiful application of the Pigeonhole Principle combined with a clever argument from graph theory, which marks the beginning of Ramsey Theory. It is often called [The Party Problem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Combinatorics/ThreeOrThree.shtml) (or Theorem on friends and strangers). The proof goes like this:

Take a $K_{6}$ (complete graph of 6 vertices) so that each person corresponds to a vertex. Color the edge joining A and B red if A and B know each other, and blue if they do not. Do this for all 15 edges of the graph. The claim will be proved if we can show that there will always be a triangle with monochromatic edges in our graph.
Take any vertex $V$ of our bicolored graph. We know that 5 edges "leave" the vertix $V$. Now, from the the Pigeonhole Principle $V$ must have at least three edges adjacent to it that have the same color. Assume without loss of generality that this color is red. Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be the endpoints of three red edges adjacent to $V$. 
[image]
Now if any edge of the triangle $XYZ$ is red, then that edge, and the two edges joining that edge to $V$ are red. So, we have a triangle with three red edges. (and we are done) Otherwise, if the triangle $XYZ$ does not have a red edge, then it has three blue edges. (and again we are done)

I love those kind of examples because they use *elementary* tools, but the ideas behind them are profound. Many astonishing examples of this kind can be found at the first two chapters and chapter thirteen of Miklós Bóna's *A Walk Through Combinatorics*. I hope that I helped you.

Answer (score 9):

I would go for the proof by contradiction of an infinite number of primes, which is fairly simple:

- Assume that there is a finite number of primes.
- Let $G$ be the set of **all** primes $P_1,P_2,...,P_n$.
- Compute $K = P_1 \times P_2 \times ... \times P_n + 1$.
- If $K$ is prime, then it is obviously **not** in $G$.
- Otherwise, **none** of its prime factors are in $G$.
- Conclusion: $G$ is **not** the set of **all** primes.

Comment: Yes great idea!

Comment: @Sky: I didn't say "Euclid's", I just said "a proof by contradiction" which is what the proof above is, and in any case, there's no reason to down-vote me for this!!!

Comment: @Peter: Thanks :)

Comment: @barakmanos I did not, I was just letting you know :)

Comment: @Sky: Well, somebody did, and I hate people do that without leaving a comment explaining why. So I apologize for that, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: You are right. It's stupid to downvote a question without reason. That's why I upvoted it ;)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you can make a much better argument: “give me some prime numbers, any number of them, I'll show you a different one”. In particular there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: @egreg: Thank you for the advice. I think that the argument given in my answer is clear enough. Of course, I can always improve it, but editing an answer here usually results with more down-votes. I've already had $3$ of those, without even any comment explaining why (!!!), and I was just trying to contribute to OP's question by giving an example of a basic proof. So I wish not put any more effort into this answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: @egreg How does your argument show that there are infinitely many primes?

Comment: @JiK No finite set of primes contains all primes.

Answer (score 9):

During my first semester of the career our calculus teacher taught us the concept of an infinite sum using some fractals. ATM I thought it was cool, since it introduced us to the wonders of "infinity" using visual motivations. The first example could be the visual proof that $\sum 2^{-i}$ converges.

After that she discussed some subtleties about infinite sums and proceeded to calculate the perimeter of the [Koch snowflake](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Koch_snowflake#Perimeter_of_the_Koch_snowflake) (if you're feeling bold you could also calculate its area). This is extremely cool since you can see how the perimeter increases and opens an interesting debate about convergence.

The other example I remember, which is very cool too, is calculating the length of some infinite trees (not exclusively binary, but this would suffice to impress the students).

I'm sure there are other very cool examples involving fractals or limits which any student can understand. These problemas have the advantage of introducing the students to some basic tools to "manage infinity", which is fundamental for every maths student.

Comment: That a snowflake is cool doesn't surprise me....

Answer (score 9):

Gambling.

What got me interested in probability theory when I was in school was that I would be able to use probability to gamble. This usually makes probability much more fun.

(Of course, don't use it too excessively)

Comment: This would have been my answer. Have the students actually gamble tokens of some kind, but then convince them that the house always wins.

Comment: Just like in 'The Wire' ;)

Comment: @Keith Problem is, the 2 games we analyzed, craps and poker, had a house edge < 1%.

Comment: @VladimirLenin Are you sure it was Poker? The house has no edge in poker because players play against other players, not the house. The house just takes a cut of each pot. You are probably thinking of blackjack im assuming.

Comment: @Loocid Yes, it was blackjack. My apologies.

Comment: @downvoter What is your reason?

Comment: "So what are simple proofs or visual examples that made you love math?" Is this answer a proof or a visual example?

Comment: @Jik Yes, it is an example.

Answer (score 6):

When I was in high school, I did not really have to do "proofs." In geometry, we used substitution many times to "prove" identities. I did not really understand these substitutions all the time in geometry because I only had one choice in most problems. When I learned the algebra side of substitution, the picture became much clearer. I grew to love math because of the substitutions one could do. All of these problems can be done with substitution or with a picture.

- The proof of the quadratic formula. Complete the square with a,b,c all letters (for review). Then use the substitution $x=y+m$, substitute, solve for $m$ in the middle term, substitute again, solve for $y$, then back substitute $y=x-m$ and finish.
- Using this equation $x^n -1 = (x-1)(x^{n-1}+ \ldots + 1)$ always intrigued me especially using the substitution "S".
- Speaking of sums $1+2+3+ ... + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. use "S" to prove that one again.
- Proof that every odd number is the difference of 2 squares. (just use $0^2=0, \ 1^2=1, \ 2^2=4, \ 3^2=9$ etc.)

Once I understood substitution, I could take definitions in math and substitute them into the problem I was working. If algebra seems too dry, then pictures can be used for the last 3 bullets.

Comment: You were lucky; I remember having to prove every theorem in the textbook, by number. I was never very good at it.

Answer (score 6):

In my $10^{th}$ mathematics book there was something given about the seven bridge problem. There was no proof given in the book so I tried it but I failed. I got a new book "Mathematical Circle(Russian experience)" in this book I found a chapter on **graph theory**. In that book I found the proof of the [seven bridge problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Bridges_of_K%C3%B6nigsberg), it was a very clean proof.

Another topic is **invariant** which nice and easy to understand.

In **probability** you may like to see [Monty Hall problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem).

Answer (score 6):

[Cutting a bagel into linked halves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dN8AwGUaqDA) is impressive to any audience. Just make sure to make a full twist: cutting along a Moebius band would produce a bigger and thinner bagel rather than linked halves.

Answer (score 5):

Infinite monkey theorem, Berry's paradox and then combine the two to show that while almost all files larger than 1 terrabyte cannot be generated by a self-extracting program to a size that will fit on a 4 GB memory stick, the proof that it can't be done in any particular case, cannot exist.

Answer (score 5):

There's so many interesting subjects, that I can't even organize them systematically. Here are some that come in mind in arbitrary order:

- The geometric series convergence illustrated by a perspective view of a railroad track or blocks of buildings along a street.
- Classic geometry constructions by a straightegde and compass.
- Plane tilings.
- Ellipses constructed inside parallelograms by intersecting families of rays.
- Curves emerging from families of straight lines obtained by shifting and rotating a line.
- Various figures fitting problems (what conditions must a polygon fit to have an inscribed circle? or a circumscribed circle? Can  we circumscribe a square on any bounded shape on plane?)
- Graph problems, including coloring a map (with a five colors easily proven with Euler characteristic of a convex polyhedron).
- A paradox of finite volume with infinite surface (Torricelli trumpet aka Gabriel's Horn).
- Pythagoras' theorem with a variety of proofs.
- Various examples of reasoning — and unsolvable problems, like a barber paradox.
- Explainig some optical results with a ray geometry (why you need a mirror half of your height to see your whole body – and why it's independent on the distance; why a ray falling between two perpendicular mirrors returns parallel to the original direction – and how it makes them give a reverted image).
- The Cantor theorem of a power set proof by constructing $\{a\in A: a \notin f(a)\}$.
- Pidgeon principle.
- Solids sections and unrolling (what shape is the surface of a tea in a glass? – an ellipse; why do squirrels chase each other around a tree along a helix? – because it is a straight line when unrolled; what shape is a toilet paper tube slant cut when unrolled? – a sinusoid; .........)
- Maze solving algorithms.
- Constant-width figures.

And many, many others.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked out Paul Lockhart's "[A Mathematician's Lament](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematicians-Lament-School-Fascinating-Imaginative/dp/1934137170/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1435232529&sr=8-1&keywords=a%20mathematician%27s%20lament)" and "[Measurement](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Measurement-Paul-Lockhart/dp/0674284380/ref=pd_bxgy_14_img_y)"? He describes his approach to teaching K12 math and - in the latter book - walks you through some elementary (but non-trivial) geometry.

Comment: Thanks I will check it now!

Answer (score 4):

My answer relates less to strictly mathematical proofs of specific concepts, but emphasizes drawing out the math behind stuff.  There are 3 main topics which I would split my answer into: Math toys, Cool math tricks, and Math in everyday life

**Math Toys**

*Spirographs*: The mathematical basis of spirographs are simple and definitely within the grasp of high schoolers, if a bit tedious.
[image: Spirograph]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirograph

*Tower of Hanoi*: A simple puzzle with loads of mathematics behind it.
[Tower of Hanoi http://www.activityresources.com/image.php?type=D&id=64](http://www.activityresources.com/image.php?type=D&id=64)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi

*Rubik's Cube*: Group theory can be applied to the algorithms approach to solving rubik's cubes. Probably a tad bit complicated for high-school math, but still, it's pretty cool :P
[image: Rubik's Cube]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik's_Cube_group

**Cool Math tricks**

*Approximating square roots of integer numbers to 2 decimal places*:
Say you have a non-perfect square integer x. 
Its nearest perfect square is y.
By using the quadratic formula, it is easy to prove that

$\sqrt{x} \approx \sqrt{y} + \frac{x-y}{2\times\sqrt{y}}$

E.g. $\sqrt{101} \approx 10 + \frac{1}{2\times10} = 10.05$

With some practice, you can evaluate such square roots very quickly, and impress the less mathematically inclined people.

*Telling the day of the week any arbitrary date is:*
Depending on the method you use, the trick's educational value can range from purely rout memorization, to using purely mathematical algorithms.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week

**Math in Everyday Life**

*Geometries in Everyday Life*

There are so many geometries embedded in everyday life that we don't give much thought to them. The reasons behind why certain geometries are used for various purposes are related more to structural engineering rather than mathematics, but there's great value in drawing out the importance of maths in real world applications. There are tons of examples you can give. My favourites are:

Antoni Gaudi's architectural designs
[image: Concepts]

Hyperbolic Paraboloid Vaults

[image: Vaults]

Hyperbolic Paraboloid Pringles

"According to Pringles marketing, the shape allows the snack to be securely stacked in a canister to prevent breakage during packaging and transport."
[image: Pringles]

*Golden Ratio*

Surprised no one has mentioned this yet. You could talk about anything ranging from continued fractions, the fibonacci sequence, to its recurrence in nature/architecture/etc..
[image: GR]

Answer (score 4):

["Proofs without words: Exercises in Visual Thinking"](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Kx2cjyzTIYkC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) is a book dedicated to visual proofs. The book has proofs about Geometry, Trigonometry, Calculus and also Sequences and Series. In case you run out of proofs for the class there is also a sequel of this book ["Proofs without words II: More Exercises in Visual Thinking"](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Proofs_without_Words_II.html?id=wMpwQgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y). Since, these are "exercises" no explanations are given for the proofs, and this is probably the fun part with this book.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I love Euclidean geometry proofs. Try some simple IMO or similar contest geometry problems, for example 2002 IMO no.1 or 2012 IMO no. 1 or this year or last years number 4 are all super fun and I really love reading the solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer to your question, since it's not about proofs, but it may help with the question behind your question.

The two books that turned me toward a career in mathematics were
Steinhaus's *Mathematical Snapshots* (http://store.doverpublications.com/0486409147.html), which I read as a high school freshman, and Polya's *Induction and Analogy in Mathematics* (https://archive.org/details/Induction_And_Analogy_In_Mathematics_1_, or from Amazon), which I read as a senior.

Comment: Thanks! I will certainly search for them!

Answer (score 3):

My two cents :

- Pigeonhole principle
- Real line
- Formal Languages (how to construct a word from a finite set, the
  alphabet)
- Simple harmonic motion physics and how the speed and acceleration of 
  an object are derived as first and second derivatives of the
  displacement equation.

Answer (score 2):

Proving Euler's identity has got to be one of the coolest things in math and probably perfect for high school seniors.

$$e^{i \pi}+ 1 = 0$$

Proof:

$$e^{i \theta} = i \sin{\theta} + \cos{\theta}$$

$$e^{i \pi} = i \sin{\pi} + \cos{\pi} = i (0) - 1 = -1$$

(You can prove the first line, "euler's formula" several ways depending on whether or not your students know power series or calculus)

Comment: But how do you convince them of Euler's identity?

Comment: My teacher taught it to me just after we learned power series. But without context as to what class OP is teaching, I left my answer vague.

Comment: They have had a quite a bit of complex numbers(due to my interest in that subject), so I think it could work

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see this problem until I was a freshman in college, reading Edwin Moise's Calculus I book. It was almost 40 years ago, so I am probably wrong about the details, but, here goes. He described how to prove $|x| + |y| \ge |x + y|$ using cases. Then he asked us to prove that $|u - v| \ge |u| - |v|$ and he hinted that it could be done without resorting to cases. I asked my professor about it, I asked my old high school teacher about it, I read that section of the book almost letter by letter. After a torturous week or so, I woke up one morning and knew the solution.

Let $x = u - v$ and let $y = v$. Then $|x| + |y| \ge |x + y|$ becomes
$|u-v| + |v| \ge |(u-v) + v|$ . The conclusion follows.

Substitution seems to be such a trivial thing. But it is really an extremely powerful mathematical tool.

Answer (score 1):

The proof of Thales' Theorem (that any triangle constructed using the diameter chord of a circle and a third point on the circle that doesn't coincide with the endpoints of the diameter is a right triangle) is a pretty nice one:

[image]

The triangle $\triangle OAB$ is an isoceles triangle because $OA$ and $OB$ are both radii of the circle and thus by definition must have equal length. That means that $\angle OAB = \angle OBA$, the measure of which we identify as $\alpha$. The same is true for $\triangle OBC$ and for the same reasons; the congruent angles are $\angle OBC = \angle OCB = \beta$.

Now, we know that the sum of all interior angles of a triangle is 180 degrees. The proof of that is also pretty intuitive in visual form:

[image]

We also can see by inspection that $\angle ACB = \alpha + \beta$. Therefore, the sum of the interior angles is $2\alpha + 2\beta = 180$, and when simplified by dividing everything by 2, $\alpha + \beta = 90$, and thus the third angle of a triangle of this construction is always 90 degrees, making the triangle a right triangle.

Comment: Much easier proved by the inscribed angle theorem (the angle subtans a arc of 180 deg), os its measure is 180/2=90 deg.

Answer (score 1):

How about Galileo's paradox?

Consider all the square numbers. Since every square number has an integer square root and every integer can be squared to give a square number, then even though not all integers are square numbers and both are infinite, the number of square numbers must equal the number of integers!

Comment: Hi I've noticed a few down votes which I'm a bit confused about. If someone could explain errors in the answer or why the answer is completely wrong for the question I would very much appreciate the advice. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that we can give finite result even to divergent sums like for examples the sum of all natural numbers:

$$\sum_{n\in \Bbb N}=1+2+3+4+\dots =-\frac 1{12}$$

This fact really astonished me and continues to have a sort of fashion on me :)

Comment: Oh yes I know that. I think my students will call me crazy if I try to tell them that XD

Comment: I dislike this because it's always presented as, "If $\sum_{k} (-1)^{k + 1} k = s$, then $\sum_{k} k =  - \frac{1}{3} s$." But in reality, these types of arguments are hand-waving and almost assuming the conclusion. In calculus, $\sum_{k} a_{k} = \lim_{N \to \infty} a_{1} + \cdots a_{N}$, while $\sigma_{k} k$ is an entirely different thing. It's fun, but honest presentation requires explaining that we're not "really" summing.

Banach limits might be cool, though. Almost-convergent sequences are interesting when you're explicit about what you're assuming, and let you solve $\sum_{k} (-1)^{k}$.

Comment: How did you reach the conclusion that $\sum_{n\in \Bbb N}=1+2+3+4+\dots$ equals $-1/12$? ([I think it requires some explanation](http://star.psy.ohio-state.edu/coglab/Pictures/miracle.gif)) Let's say that it does, what would that knowledge be useful for?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye It comes from the analytic continuation of the Riemann Zeta function, this and other similar result can be obtained with summation method as Cesaro's or Ramanujan' s. This has application in number theory and, surprisingly in theoretical physic.

Comment: The question was about simple proofs or visual examples. Now which one of those is this??

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen there are simple proof of this but there are a bit naive, I usually explain this like "here's the simple proof, if you don't belive it there are more rigorous ones but they are hard"

Comment: @RenatoFaraone: I see. What applications does it have in theoretical physics?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye String Theory (http://stringworld.ru/files/Polchinski_J._String_theory._Vol._1._An_introduction_to_the_bosonic_string.pdf), Casimir Effect and a few other by today, unfortunately I'm not a physicist so I can't fully understand those arguments, may the link I gave you could help you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: guess the proof]

These 3 triangles are similar, the two smallest pave the large one and their area is quadratic in the length of their hypotenuses...